# createSlice returned reducer function

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

i have this 2 files from redux tutorial:

store.js:

```js
    import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
    
    import postsReducer from '../features/posts/postsSlice'
    
    export default configureStore({
      reducer: {
        posts: postsReducer
      }
    })
```

and this is '../features/posts/postsSlice' file but the function that was exported is **postsSlice.reducer** not **postsReducer**

```js
     import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
        
        const initialState = [
          { id: '1', title: 'First Post!', content: 'Hello!' },
          { id: '2', title: 'Second Post', content: 'More text' }
        ]
        
        const postsSlice = createSlice({
          name: 'posts',
          initialState,
          reducers: {}
        })
        
        export default postsSlice.reducer
```

I want to know where the **postsReducer** function, which was imported in the store, comes from.

Comment: It is a `default` export, so you can call it anything when you import it.  The name of the variable doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of exports in JS: named exports and default exports.

A **named export** is specified with the export keyword followed by a declaration. Note that you can have multiple named exports per module. For  example:

```js
export const foo = 'hello';
export function bar() {
  return 'world';
}
```

To import a named export, we use **import** keyword followed by the name of the value you want to import in curly braces. For example:

```js
import { foo, bar } from './myModule';

console.log(foo); // 'hello'
console.log(bar()); // 'world'
```

A **default export** is a way to specify value that can be imported with any name. But you can have only one default export per module. Here is an example:

```js
export default postsSlice.reducer
```

Importing a default export is done by the **import** keyword followed by any identifier you choose - so you can use diffrent name than the one that was used in export (like in your case above)

```js
import postsReducer from '../features/posts/postsSlice';
```

You can read more about exporting and importing in JavaScript in the MDN documentation:

- Exporting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export
- Importing:
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import